# Obtaining a long-stay / long-term visa to UK or EU as a US citizen

Tags: visa, eu, us-citizens, uk-visitor-visa

I am a US citizen wanting to study full time (year-round for up to 3 years) at a fine art atelier or a 19th century curriculum art academy in either the EU or the UK.

As it stands in my research, I've come to the following roadblocks and desperately need help figuring out how to overcome these problems in order to study with my preferred atelier/academy for the entire duration of the program.

The art academies and/or atelier model of education that I am interested in pursuing IS LEGALLY NOT in the same category as an accredited University/College. Therefore, these institutions are legally unable to help sponsor a Study/Student Visa to international students (aka—me, the US citizen).

I have yet to come across any way to obtain any kind of visa in order to stay LONG TERM (at least 12 months, if not +) in the UK or EU as a US citizen.

—And yes, I have looked into freelance visas (for UK & EU) and long-stay tourist visas (for EU) and am not sure if I can apply for one of these, then "study" at an atelier...I know that I don't qualify for any of the standard list of long-stay visas in the UK. Heck, I've even looked into staying in the UK for the legal 6 months (passport route), then hopping over to the EU for a little bit to "reset" my 6 months clock for the UK...but have come to the conclusion (after more research) that I could/most likely would be kicked out of the UK for a crazy amount of time and have a permanent record of unlawful intentions of living in the UK illegally (using loopholes) written in my passport...so... What, oh what, to do?

I'm grateful for any practical advice with all this—as at this point, I've done my oodles of research, and have exhausted all ideas based on that research.

Thanks for tuning in to assist,

The Elmore Artist

Comment: There is no suitable UK visa that will allow you to do this. Entering visa-free and relying on visa runs (if you could get away with them) won’t work either because full-time study is not permitted under the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: Thank you for your comment! A follow up Q: Since the Atelier I want to study with is not legally recognized by the UK as a Tier 4 institution of study (hence why I cannot get a study visa...), would I technically be in violation of "studying" during my visit by passport?

Comment: You would be violating the Rules, yes. Also consider what you would tell Border officials about the purpose of your (repeated) visits, if asked. It’s also possible that the institution where you want to study would ask you for proof of your right to study in the UK. I’m not an expert but I would expect a reputable institution to be aware of and uphold the Immigration Rules.